# Reading a .txt into a stack

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with how to read a text file into my program so the words can be sorted alphabetically. Should I use something like a FileReader?

An example of what I'm trying to do is a .txt file that holds the statement "java is a simple object oriented and distributed and interpreted and robust and secure and dynamic."

The output should organize the words like so: and and and and distributed dynamic interpreted is java object oriented robust secure simple

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java AscendingAlphabet"
        + " test.txt");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String file = args[0];
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scanner = null;

        try {
            File f = new File(file);

            scanner = new Scanner(f);
            while (scanner.hasNext())
                names.add(scanner.next());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
        Collections.sort(names);

        for (String s : names)
            System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: What's the error? Any stack trace, i.e. `IOException`?

Comment: wildest guess `FileNotFoundException`? it seems people are more keen to help than the person who wants to be helped

Comment: where does the stack come into it?

Comment: It just prints the usage statement in line 3.

Comment: @monocyte How did you run the program?

Comment: @Soana I'm using eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there the console function in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610988/is-there-the-console-function-in-eclipse)